# Spring Boot and Amazon AWS - how to connect to S3 using Spring Cloud AWS?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, spring-boot

I'm pretty new to Spring in general, as well as Amazon AWS, so I apologize in advance if I'm doing something horribly wrong.

I can not seem to get my Spring Boot application to communicate with AWS services in any way when deployed onto Elastic Beanstalk.  I've been following the guide [here](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html#_basic_setup) to try to set my project up correctly.

I'm essentially taking the code they provide and attempting to run from my project:

```
@Component
public class Storage {

    @Autowired
    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public Storage() {

    }

    public void writeResource() throws IOException {
        Resource resource = this.resourceLoader.getResource("s3://server-images/rootFile.log");
        WritableResource writableResource = (WritableResource) resource;
        try (OutputStream outputStream = writableResource.getOutputStream()) {
            outputStream.write("test".getBytes());
        }
    }
}
```

Super, seems simple enough.  I also set my application.properties file:

```
cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey = A******A
cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey = i******K

cloud.aws.credentials.instanceProfile = true
cloud.aws.region.auto = true
```

so I set the key and secret in the profile, and then lastly, I add the stuff to the build.gradle file to get the Spring Cloud stuff:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.4.RELEASE")
        classpath("io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.2.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"

war {
    baseName = 'server'
    // version = '0.0.1'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-aws:1.0.2.RELEASE'
    }
}

//jar {
//    baseName = 'gs-spring-boot'
//    version =  '0.1.0'
//}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

dependencies {
    // tag::jetty[]
    // compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
    //    exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    //}
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")

    // Spring Cloud AWS
    compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws'

    //compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")
    // end::jetty[]
    // tag::actuator[]
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    // end::actuator[]
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.4'
}
```

Lastly, I don't know how much this matters, but I gave "AmazonS3FullAccess" and "AmazonEC2FullAccess" to the elasticbeanstalk role in AWS.  I also set permissions for "Everyone" to list/upload/delete.

So far, All I get is:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:295)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:673)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at app.data.Storage.readTerminator(Storage.java:44)
    at app.controllers.CodeController.getCode(CodeController.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    ... 54 common frames omitted
```

As I can see, the resourceLoader isn't getting anything

Maybe there is some permission problems?  Maybe I have misconfigured it?  I figure this shouldn't be this hard, so I'm definitely doing something wrong!  If anyone has any ideas, they are more than welcome.

Comment: Saw this post, and I am a learner like you are :) 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23407515/amazons3-connection-management

Answer (score 3):

Brian.

If the cause is wrong permissions you should check if your user(you created in IAM) has corresponding permissions(Policies):

AmazonS3FullAccess,
AWSConnector

Hope this will help.

Comment: I ended up ditching Spring Cloud and just running with the AWS client library.  Thanks for the response though!

Comment: Got the same problem, +1 Vladimir :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if your bucket policy allows you to put **un-encrypted objects**. If this is not the reason, there may be other reasons why AWS S3 would not allow your objects to be uploaded. When you use the native AWS library, they set a lot of defaults, but spring libraries may not be setting those defaults.

I was getting the same error, until I figured out that my bucket policy was blocking any un-encrypted objects from being uploaded.

```
    {
        "Sid": "RequiredEncryptedPutObject",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:PutObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotEquals": {
                "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": [
                    "AES256",
                    "aws:kms"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
```