# Is it recommended to use AmazonS3Client as a singleton?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3

When using an `AmazonS3Client` in a webapplication, is it recommended to create **one instance for the whole lifetime** of the application or should I **create a new instance** every time I'm doing an upload to S3?

I can't find any documentation on this other than the Java client where a [singleton approach is recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23407515/amazons3-connection-management).

I'm interested in this because for `HttpClient` it is known that [you should not create more than one instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043679/how-many-httpclients-should-i-create).

For example, is there some kind of pooling / connection management in the `AmazonS3Client`? There is `AmazonS3Config.ConnectionLimit`, but I can't find a lot of documentation about it. How does this work when you use `Parallel.ForEach` to get maximum throughput?

Comment: @john-wu I've reworded my question slightly. My question is not fully answered with the answers from the duplicate.

Comment: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16354966/does-amazon-s3-have-a-connection-pool). Please [search before asking](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17498).

Comment: @JohnWu that's Java unfortunately.